# How to add headers to only specific files with nginx

Tags: nginx, header

I have pictures, and I want to add their headers to max, I have profile pictures which can be changed and post pictures, I want to add headers only for post pictures, but not to profile pictures, I have no idea how can I manage this. thank you, this is my configuration,

```
this is the path of posts, /post/name-of-the-picture.jpg

this is the path of users, /user/name-of-the-picture.jpg
```

I only want to add headers to post path

```
location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
   expires max;
   add_header Pragma public;
   add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Currently we have **two options** to solve this:

**Option 1:**

> *Duplicated locations*: NGINX looks for the best match. (a little better performance)

```
location /post/ {
    post config stuff;
    .
    .
    .
}    
location ~* ^/post/.*\.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
    post/files.(css|js|png|gif) config stuff;
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
location /user/ {
    user folder config stuff;
    .
    .
    .
}    
location ~* ^/user/.*\.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
    user/files.(css|js|png|gif) config stuff;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**Option 2:**

> *Nested locations*: Filtered by extension in the inner location blocks

```
location /post/{
    ...

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
location /user/{
    ...

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that you can nest `location` blocs!