# NGINX serve all files in certain directory as txt files, but not autoindex pages

Tags: nginx, web

I have a directory on my server which has a bunch of shell scripts. This directory is autoindexed, but when I try to open the files in my browser, they prompt for download instead of opening as text. I can easily map the filetype "sh" to text/plain in the mime.types file, but some of the scripts don't have that sh extension. How can I serve all files in a certain directory as .txt files so that they are opened in the user's browser instead of prompting the user for download?

Edit: adding `add_header Content Type text/plain;` to that directory's location block does show all of the scripts as text, but it also affects the autoindex page.

Comment: This is behaviour of your browser use command line tool like curl if you want to get text output. Certain file like pdf, jpg are opened whereas other are downloaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add headers to only specific files with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945223/how-to-add-headers-to-only-specific-files-with-nginx)

Comment: Use: `types {}` and `default_type test/plain;`

Answer (score 2):

That should be `add_header Content-Type text/plain;` (instead of `add_header Content Type text/plain;` , right?)

But you're right about it affecting all files. It even renders HTML as plain text and displays the source when visited with a browser.
I'm experiencing the same problem as you have (files with many different extensions, most of which plain text)